# Types for ChartJS Options?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

Does anyone know if there is an updated set of types for ChartJS?

There is a package [`@types/chartjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chartjs), but it's deprecated.

It would be nice to get autocomplete when defining options.

Currently with pure JS:

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {},
  options: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

It would be nice if we could do:

```js
const config: ChartJSOptions = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {},
  options: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

Comment: Read the deprecation message? _"'@types/chartjs' is now '@types/chart.js'"_. Also it looks from https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js like chart.js has bundled types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import it:

```
import { ChartConfiguration } from 'chart.js'

const config: ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {},
  options: {},
  plugins: []
}
```